# How to use Ionic keyboard on Electron/ionic App

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, electron

I'm creating an App with Electron and Ionic (in the future all will be on ionic only) but i can't use the ionic Keyboard on text area.

I try to use the ionic Keyboard included in Ionic v4 like that:

***app.module.ts***

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
@NgModule({
  [...]
  ],
  providers: [ 
    (...),
    Keyboard
  ],
});
```

***my-page.ts***

```
import { Keyboard  } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
import { IonInput } from '@ionic/angular';
@ViewChild('InputK') InputK: IonInput;

constructor( private keyboard: Keyboard) {
}
public showKeyboard(){
   this.keyboard.setFocus()
}
```

On the input in my html i just put #InputK (click)=‘showKeyboard()’ but i won’t work…

I’ve you got solution for this kind of problem ?

Kind Regards for your time.

I don't get any error code, it just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard plugin doesn't seem to support Electron. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard:

> Supported Platforms
>
> - Android
> - iOS

If you need a virtual keyboard on text inputs, you can enable the tablet mode in Windows (through the notifications center at the bottom right of the screen). This should open the keyboard automatically when you touch an input.